# Add Git log as table to InDesign Document

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, indesign-scripting, tables

I use InDesign CC as the last step in document processing. The source is written in Markdown and converted via pandoc to an InCopy document which gets linked to a text frame in InDesign.

The whole process is described in [Markdown to Indesign with Pandoc (via ICML)](http://networkcultures.org/digitalpublishing/2014/10/08/markdown-to-indesign-with-pandoc-via-icml/).

For version control of the Markdown files I use Git.

Is there a way to link the Git log to an InDesign table to have a version list at the beginning of the document?

So, when I do a commit in Git, the table can be updated via an action script or the like?

Comment: You could create an InCopy document and place it. Any change to to doc will be noticed by InDesign. Another solution would be a post commit hook that triggers an Extendscript run. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320580/how-to-execute-an-indesign-extendscript-from-command-line) and the [git hook docs](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: You wouldn't even have to make an incopy file if you can get the git log output as an xml — indesign is really good at importing xml and auto styling it (you match paragraph/character styles to the xml tags). XML files are linkable and updateable, as you generate/overwrite the xml file, you update and, provided you've mapped the tags to styles correctly, voila, magically updated table/list!